# swing - short-time highlight of a component

Tags: java, swing, swingworker

I have a JTable, where a user can select a single row. If that happens, i want to "highlight" another part of the page for a short time to indicate that this is the part of the page that changed after the user interaction.

So my question is: What's the best way to achieve this? At the moment i did it by setting the background color of that panel and starting a SwingWorker which sets the Color back after a short delay. It works as intended, but is it a good idea to use a SwingWorker like that? Are there any drawbacks to that approach? How would you solve this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I guess a `SwingTimer` would be a better option as it doesn't need a separate thread, it just schedules a runnable for the main event loop.

Comment: If you like this suggestion, I can turn it into an answer.

Comment: Thank's, that is exactly what i was looking for. As you responded first, i will accept your solution if you turn it into an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess a Swing Timer would be a better option as it reuses a single thread for all scheduled events and executes the event code on the main event loop. So, inside your `SelectionListener` code you do:

```
// import javax.swing.Timer;

final Color backup = componentX.getBackground();
componentX.setBackground(Color.YELLOW);
final Timer t = new Timer(700, new ActionListener() {
  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    componentX.setBackground(backup);
  }
});
t.setRepeats(false);
t.start();
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend a swing Timer (javax.swing.Timer). (do NOT use the Timer class in Java.util)

This is where you make the timer:

```
Timer t = new Timer(loopTime,actionListener)//loopTime is unimportant for your use of this
t.setInitialDelay(pause)//put the length of time between starting the timer and the color being reverted to normal
t.setRepeats(false);//by default, timer class runs on loop.
t.start();//runs the timer
```

It probably makes sense to hold on to a reference to the timer, and then just call t.start when you need it.

You need to implement an action listener to handle the timer events. I can edit this if you don't know how to do that, but as you are already doing stuff with Swing I figure it shouldn't be a problem.