# How to highlight an updated component in short time

Tags: java, swing, swingworker

When user logs into the swing application, and if any new/existing components are introduced/modified, those components need to be highlighted.

So my question is: What's the best way to achieve this? It should be a generic solution as in every release/delivery, I have to use this feature.

I tried the below post below post,
[swing - short-time highlight of a component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11396859/swing-short-time-highlight-of-a-component)

Whenever the new release happen, to notify the user this is modified/new changes.To indicate user this is new changes.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LSeDg.png)

Comment: 1) *"I tried the below post.."* What happened when you tried it? 2) For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).